Delphi-Android app: Could not load SSL Library (NEW POST)
I have read many posts about this problem and I have tried many combinations/advices about it without success. Here is my test applet :
unit uTestSSL;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, System.IOUtils,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm13 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form13: TForm13;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses
  IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders,
  IdSSLOpenSSL,
  IdHTTP;

procedure TForm13.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  F : TStringStream;
  s : TStringStream;
  res : string;
begin
  with TidHTTP.Create(nil) do begin
    IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(TPath.GetLibraryPath); // when I deploy to library\lib\arm64\
    //IdOpenSSLSetLibPath('library/lib/armeabi-v7a/');
    //IdOpenSSLSetLibPath('./assets/internal'); // when I deploy to ./assets/internal
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
    IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
    Request.Pragma := 'no-cache';
    s := TStringStream.Create('some XML text');
    s.Position := 0;
    F := TStringStream.Create;
    showmessage('****'+OpenSSLVersion+'****');  //reports nothing
    try
      post('https://www1.gsis.gr/wsaade/RgWsPublic2/RgWsPublic2?WSDL',s,F);
    except
      showmessage('==='+WhichFailedToLoad+'==='); //reports Faild to load /library/lib/armeabi-v7a (or arm64)
      showmessage('****'+OpenSSLVersion+'****');  //reports nothing
    end;
  end;
end;

end.

and my deploying schema is :

Can someone make this example (or a fixed version) to work, please?
PS. My Delphi version is 11.3 and Android version 12

In your deploy screenshot, you are deploying the OpenSSL files to the ./assets/internal folder. Such assets are private to the APK and can't be accessed using file paths, so FireMonkey's StartupCopy unit extracts the assets at app startup to the device's storage. You can then use TPath.GetDocumentsPath() to access the asset files at runtime. This is explained in detail in Delphi's documentation:
Creating an Android App: Loading and Deploying Files

When you deploy your application for the Android target platform, if you plan to provide files along with your application to load those files at run time, you must first decide whether you want to have them on the internal device memory or on a external memory (for example, an SD card). After you decide, use the Deployment Manager to place those files in the assets\internal (internal) or assets (external) folder during deployment.
Use the following code to locate those files at run time:
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'filename')  { Internal }
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetPublicPath, 'filename')  { External }



On a side note: your code is leaking all of the objects you are Create'ing. You need to Free them when you are done using them. Since 10.4 onward, Delphi no longer uses ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) to manage object lifetimes on mobile platforms, so you have to manage them yourself, just like on desktop platforms.

Remy, I deploy the .so files to assets\internal (I can see them there) and use IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(TPath.GetDocumentsPath) but I always get the same error! This is driving me crazy! Am I missing some setting? Are .so files not suitable? PS. At screenshot I have '/' against ''. Ι fixed it

Remy, I noticed that the size of the .so files for different platforms is different. This shows, in my opinion, that I haven't selected the right files (I'm using armeabi-v7a). Which is the right one to use for Android 12?

@JimPapas what makes you think they should be the same size on different platforms? Makes sense to me that they wouldn't be, since the binary requirements are different for each platform. I don't know why the .so files are not working for you. Everything I know about this tells me that assets\internal + TPath.GetDocumentsPath should work, unless something new on Android has changed and is breaking this.

Remy, I meant that in armeabi-v8a and armeabi-v7a the .so files are of different size and I was wondering if this means that the android 12 version needs other files eg arm64 version that is not in the zip file.

@JimPapas not that I'm aware of. But, I don't do any mobile development and haven't checked the .so files myself. But they have been available for awhile and I haven't seen anyone have trouble using them.

Android moved away from OpenSSL to BoringSSL.

@LegitLearner True, and Indy does not support BoringSSL at this time. However, on some Android devices, an app can deploy their own copy of OpenSSL locally and work just fine. But on some devices, BoringSSL is pre-loaded in memory and may conflict with a local OpenSSL deploy. https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/166

Try calling IdSSLOpenSSL.OpenSSLVersion() and see if it reports OpenSSL or BoringSSL is being used.
